# Why I can't divide $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}$ and $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had an differential equation exam last semester. There was a question I never found out how I could answer. At a part of the question I faced:

$\frac{u'''}{u''} = \cot(x)u+x$

And it was asked to make it first-order Linear and then solve it. I simply wrote

$\frac{u'''}{u''}= u'$. Then wrote it like $u' - \cot(x)u = x$, 
but I know the first part is not correct at all. I never had the chance to ask the teacher or anyone what should one do in this situation?

I think I had a confusion and it's root is the notation
when you could write $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $(D)y$ so $\frac{d^3y}{d^3x}$ could be $(D^3)y$.

Is there a way to lower this equations order?

Comment: Do you agree with my edit? Did you meant $\cot(xu)$ or $\cot(x)u$?

Comment: @Cornman cot(x)u cause first-order Linear Equation is like y'+p(x)y = q(x)

Comment: Are you sure that the task demands "first order **linear**"? Or just a first order system (in the state vector $y=(u,u',u'')$)?

Comment: @Lutzl i'm sure about linear part, and the only linear we've learned was the first-order.

Comment: Was this a written exam? Was the question written exactly like this? If this was an oral exam I strongly suspect you misunderstood or misremembered the question. This can happen when the flow of the interview is broken and some point is attacked from several, possibly incompatible angles.

Comment: @LutzL Nope it was first a big function of `sinx` and `cosx` and `y''` and `y'''` in the question, and then a substitution of y=xu were Asked, After bunch of simplification i had this. Actually i don't remember if right side was cotx+x i think it was cotx only. Im 100% sure about the u'''/u''

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{d^3 y}{d x^3}$ doesn't represent $\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx}$.
It represents the iterated operator of differentiation.

$\frac{d^3 y}{d x^3} = \frac{d }{d x} ( \frac{d }{d x} ( \frac{d }{d x} ( y)))$

You can't lower the order of differentiation, that's the whole point of differential equation. You can do some tricks like change of variable $y=u'$ and see how it goes, but it requires solving for $y$, then for $u$ which is strictly equivalent.

Comment: i had same idea first but as u see there is x and u present in equation and by that substitution there would be 3 variables in equation.

Comment: Actually by what u said u'''/u'' = u'/u is it correct?

Comment: @no0ob No it is NOT correct.